# validation using sstream failing

Tags: c++, validation, integer, sstream

```
cout << "\nPlease enter x-ordinate: ";

cin >> test;
stringstream ss(test);
ss >> x;
while(ss.fail())
{
ss.str("");
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(256, '\n');  
cout << "Please enter integer: \n";
cin >> test;
stringstream ss(test);
ss >> x;
cout << x << ss;    
}
```

Hi, I am trying to test whether the user's input is an integer or not, by using sstream to check if it can be converted into the integer x, but once i enter in a valid integer, the while loops still proves to be true and the loop continues on. Can anoyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point streaming from `cin` into a `string`, creating a `istringstream`, then streaming from there to your number: it just leaves room for extra types of errors, such as `"12x"` being treated as `12` and the `x` ignored rather than producing a warning/error message for the user.

You can read more directly as follows:

```
const char* prompt = "\nPlease enter x-coordinate: ";
while (cout << prompt && !(cin >> x))
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(256, '\n');  
    prompt = "Please enter integer: \n";
}
```

If you don't need to change the prompt, you can put it directly into the loop:

```
while (cout << "\nPlease enter x-coordinate: " && !(cin >> x))
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(256, '\n');  
    std::out << "Please enter an integer.\n";
}
```

---

Note: you will see something a bit like your first effort, where the reading to the `string` uses `getline` rather than `>>`, and that can be a good practice as it let you count line numbers (more useful for parsing files than `std::cin`) and check values appear on lines alongside other expected data.  That looks like this:

```
std::string line;
while (std::cout << "Enter coordinate:" &&
       getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    if (iss >> x)
         break;
    std::cout << "Error - invalid coordinate, please enter an integer\n";
}
...use x...
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Just wanted to ask since I'm pretty new at this.
    while (cout << "\nPlease enter x-coordinate: " && !(cin >> x))
the while loop actually executes the output? i thought the while loop checks if the condition is true only? which means it actually attempts to put cin into the integer x?

Comment: by the way, for the validation of the integer, when i input '1asdf', it actually goes thru.. any idea why?

Comment: @user6235245: it's because each `>>` input operation succeeds if able to parse out compatible input, so from `"1asdf"` you first parse out `int` `1`, then it would be the *next* parsing operation that might fail or detect a problem.  If you want to ensure there's whitespace after the `int`, you can use `while (cout << "\nPlease enter x-coordinate: " && !(cin >> x || !isspace(cin.peek()))) ...` ([`std::isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) is in the `<cctype>` header).  For the `getline` version, `if (is >> x >> std::skipws && is.eof()) break;` to detect trailing crap.

Comment: /*while (cout << "\nPlease enter x-coordinate: " && getline(cin, line))
     {
     iss(line);
     if (iss >> x)
     //string leftovers;
     getline(iss, leftovers);
     if (leftovers == "")
     break;
     cout << "Error, Please try again.";
     }*/'

i tried doing this to check if after the conversion of stringstream to integer, if im not wrong the rubbish(alphabets) will be left inside the stringstream? but this doesnt work either

Comment: @user6235245: I'm confused... you want to check, I suggest something, you come back telling me something completely different doesn't work...? ;-.  Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Sorry I just tried it out, and your method work. Do you mind explaining why !isspace(cin.peek() will work? Because i searched it up and it says it checks for whitespaces and how does it help to check for the rubbish left behind in the stream?

Comment: @user6235245: so, the `cin >> x || !isspace(cin.peek()` approach prompts again if there's not some manner of whitespace after the number - which could be a space, a tab, a "linefeed", "formfeed" or newline.  So, if you typed "12 a" it'd extract "12" for your x coordinate, then say you have another `while` loop to read a y coordinate - *that* loop would reject `a` and prompt for an integer.  This approach is common - it lets you do things like `echo 12 23 | ./my_program" to supply `cin` with values for x and y, with whitespace between, even though there's only one line.

Comment: The `is >> x >> std::skipws && is.eof()` approach is for when you want to make sure there's exactly and only one number on that line - the `skipws` should make it to the end of the line, which for a single-line `istringstream` will also set the `eof` flag.  So, if `eof()` is not set after `skipws` then you know there's other unwanted content on the line and can prompt the user to try again.

Answer (score 1):

There's a slight problem with the code you have... you have two totally different variables with the same name, one is used in the loop condition, one is inside the body of the loop. Those two variables are not related or connected in any way.

Instead reuse the first `ss` variable, by setting its string:

```
...
cin >> test;
ss.str(test);
...
```

You also don't clear the status of the `ss` stream in the loop, only of `cin`, which is the reason your loop never ends.

I would also suggest you use the fact that a stream can be used as a boolean condition, and that the `operator>>` function returns a reference to the stream, then you could do something like

```
cout << "\nPlease enter x-ordinate: ";
getline(cin, test);

istringstream ss(test);
while(!(ss >> x))
{
    ss.clear();
    cout << "Please enter integer: \n";
    getline(cin, test);
    ss.str(test);
}
```

See [here for an example of the above](http://ideone.com/zeouFn).

---

Of course one could use `cin` directly as well:

```
int x;
while (!(cin >> x))
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "Please enter integer: \n";
}
```

See [here for an example of the above](http://ideone.com/tQ7GoP).

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you

Comment: @user6235245 I just added a note about that, because you don't clear the status of `ss`.

Comment: Hi, i just tried your code, apparently its still stuck at "Please enter integer" even after i repeatedly entered 1.

Comment: what is the point of using string stream here, can't this check be done using *cin* itself ?

Comment: i tried using cin >> x , but if its not an integer type, the program goes haywire

Comment: @bkVnet If the input fails, then the invalid input is still left in the input buffer of `cin`. You can do like this, or use `cin` and skip/ignore the invalid input manually.

Answer (score 0):

what type is the test variable ? a string ? 
You could try that generic parser taking a string as input :

```
template<class T>
bool tryparse(const string word, T& res)
{
   istringstream parser(word);
   bool status = (parser >> res);
   return status;
}
```

Comment: test is a string, when i try to cin >> ss (stringstream type)
there is an error apparently

Comment: If test is a string and you want to check if it can be parsed to an int you could write : 

    if(tryparse<int>(test, var)) { /* use value in var */ } else { /* error */ }